# Downgrading from ASP.net 4 MVC 2 to ASP.net 3.5 MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am a bit of beginner with ASP.net MVC, and built most of my original app while following a book.

I am trying to downgrade a project because of server limitations.

I have resolved a number of errors, but now I am stuck on this on:
If I build it builds ok, but when I press play, I get this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'dynamic' could not be found (are  you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It occurs on this line:

> [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute()]
>
> **Line 142:    public class views_rooms_index_aspx : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, System.Web.IHttpHandler {**
> Line 143:
> Line 144:        private static bool @__initialized;

Which I believe probably originates from somewhere like this in my View:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
```

Is System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage something that you can only do in asp.net 4? What do I need to replace this with for ASP.net 3.5?

Answer (score 2):

The `dynamic` keyword was introduced in .NET 4.0, and will not be available in any version earlier than that.

I believe the default base class for an mvc view in MVC with ASP.NET 3.5 was `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage`, without any generic type. If you want to add a strongly typed model (which is recommended whenever you want to pass data from the controller to the view) you should create a view model class, and replace `dynamic` with the namespace qualified name of your view model.

Example: you want to pass a string `name` that you got from somewhere in your controller, to the Home/Index view. Do the following:

1. Create a class `HomeIndexViewModel` (name doesn't matter, but this is a good one ;) ) in the `Models` folder of your project, and give it a `public string Name {get; set;}` property.
2. In your controller, insantiate this class and set the name. Pass it to the view using the `return View(model);` overload.
3. Make your view inherit `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<YourProject.Models.HomeIndexViewModel>`. You can now access the name using `Model.Name` in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Inherits` attribute:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>"
```

Has the `dynamic` type as the generic type - change it to the correct ViewModel type.

For example:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ProductViewModel>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers above cover it pretty well.
you might consider using:
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

i have used it to convert my website to web application and it really helps.